# What is the meaning of AKA abbreviation?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

I have saw this expression been used very often in colloquial textual conversations (as in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/60028/105169) for example), but I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A.k.a. Or aka means  (and is an abbreviation for) “also known as”.
It is used when someone has another name or title, such as “James Brown, aka the Godfather of Soul” https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/aka

(I personally always thought of James Brown’s aka as “the hardest working man in show business,” but that’s not really important here)

It is also used for things, not just people, as in the example question you cited. A good example of this usage would be the way plant and animal species often have a scientific name and a “common” name in a modern language: “The Black Eyed Susan (aka: Rudbeckia hirta) is a lovely, daisy-like flower and a North America native.” https://plantcaretoday.com/black-eyed-susan.html

It is also commonly used in application forms or legal documents to indicate names previously used (as when someone changes their name upon marriage, divorce, or for some other reason), or police records to indicate aliases (fake or stolen identities used by criminals to escape detection). See https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/alias

Comment: I find its use as a noun to be incorrect. If you want a noun, there's "alias", "sobirquet", etc.

Comment: @Acccumulation "**sobriquet**", not _sober K_ :)

Comment: While using “aka” as a noun is somewhat awkward to my ears and probably technically incorrect, it is commonly used that way in law enforcement settings, so if you do that sort of work you’ll run across it.

Answer (score 1):

> aka
>   ( eɪ keɪ eɪ ) also a.k.a.
>   aka is an abbreviation for 'also known as'.
>   aka is used especially when referring to someone's nickname or stage name.
>   ...the writer Barbara Vine, aka Ruth Rendell.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aka